# Plain Sql in Slick to Match Char Column?

Tags: scala, slick

After importing slick's MySQL driver,

```
scala> import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

I then define a `Char`:

```
scala> val x: Char = 'x'
x: Char = x
```

Finally, I attempted to write a plain SQL query:

```
scala> sql"""SELECT name FROM table WHERE column = ${x}"""
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit 
      value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Char]
        sql"""SELECT name FROM table WHERE column = ${x}"""
```

But I got the above error.

How can I write plain SQL to match against a single character?

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no SQL data type to represent a single character. There are data types that can represent a sequence of characters(CHAR or VARCHAR). And so, the SetParameter is not implemented for 'Char' in slick. You can check out the default SetParameter implementations [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/SetParameter.fm#L21-L46).

If the data type of '**column**' in mysql is one of 'CHAR' or 'VARCHAR', you should declare a **String** instead of **Char**. That should solve your problem.